# What is the complexity of determining if a state is entangled?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-algorithms, entanglement, complexity-theory

I have been looking around for an answer to this question but can't really come up with anything. Given some oracle, $U$, that maps $| 0 \rangle$ to $| \psi \rangle$, is there some algorithm that determines whether $| \psi \rangle$ is entangled or separable?

I think there must be an algorithm for this, but is it in BQP? ($O(poly(N))$ where $N$ is the number of qubits), or is it hard?

Comment: That's a very good question. One way to upperbound the query complexity is to do tomography of $|\psi\rangle$ and then use some classical method. This will be obviously exponential in $N$. There must be much better methods of doing it, though.

Comment: [arXiv:1308.5788](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.5788) studies various forms of this problem and may be relevant.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At least when the state that you're testing is a mixed state (rather than known to be a pure state), there's been quite a bit of work on this. In 2003, Gurvits showed that the problem is NP hard. There's a more recent [result](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4507) that strengthens the statement. It perhaps doesn't directly answer your question about the quantum complexity, especially as these start from a matrix description of the state rather than just a copy of the state, but is certainly suggestive.

In practice, there are algorithms that work pretty well, such as [this one](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.2751).

You might also like to check out the body of work that  Lawrence Ioannou produced during his PhD. It's available on the [arxiv](https://arxiv.org/search/quant-ph?searchtype=author&query=Ioannou%2C%20L%20M).

Answer (score 3):

This question requires a careful modification, so that one would be able to speak about the complexity of a solution.

Suppose you have an algorithm that guaranties to run in time $<f(n)$, i.e. makes no more than $f(n)$ queries to the oracle $U$.
And it's required it should output an answer with the error probability no more than $1/3$.

It doesn't matter how big $f(n)$ is, there is always a state $|\psi\rangle$ which is very close to the boundary of the set of entangled states.
For such a state your algorithm won't be able to decide with the error less than 1/3.

In other words, the time bound $f(n)$ can't be independent of $|\psi\rangle$.

A natural modification would be to consider a weak membership problem.
That is, if $|\psi\rangle$ is within the Euclidean distance $\beta > 0$ from the boundary of the set of entangled states.
See e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4507.

Comment: I don't see the problem with the weak membership formulation. We can do tomography on $|\psi\rangle$, so we know that with probability $p$ it is within $\epsilon$ of the reconstructed state. We then apply a deterministic method to the reconstructed state, and then we can decided whether it is within $\beta$ of the boundary of the separable states.

Comment: Right, we can simply discard failed tomography cases, if their probability is small.

Comment: how is "run time" defined here? In terms of the number of states consumed, or something else? Of do you assume you already have a classical description of the quantum state, and then you just mean computational time required to determine separability from the classical description?

Comment: @glS I assume we want to minimize the number of queries to the oracle $U$. But apparently the complexity of a classical part is also important, since we don't know how to solve it efficiently given a classical description (for mixed states).

Comment: Apparently OP is asking about the query complexity for pure states only. They should clarify.