# How to find that if two quantum states are entangled or not using quantum circuit?

Tags: measurement

Let us consider, we can easily prepare 2 distinct single qubit quantum states psi1 and psi2 in quantum registers (q1 and q2) in a quantum circuit. How to find out the entanglement status of these two quantum states using quantum circuit?

Comment: Are we talking about pure states or mixed states? The answer is much more complicated in the latter case.

Comment: I asked a similar question before [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/31881/what-is-the-complexity-of-determining-if-a-state-is-entangled?noredirect=1#comment42153_31881). The answer I accepted was mainly about mixed states, but I don't think much is known about the pure state case.

Comment: Not strictly a circuit but https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/how-do-i-show-that-a-two-qubit-state-is-an-entangled-state could be helpful